# Embedding an Outlook Exchange Calendar in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way (ideally an easy one) to embed an Outlook Exchange Calendar in MediaWiki? The wiki is on an intraweb and I'd like to show the calendar on the main wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get away with only supporting MSIE users, you could do it with an ActiveX control: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=70

This requires all users to have MSIE and Outlook installed on their local computers. Everyone must also have access to the calendar being displayed.